# How should I read 西棟?

Tags: readings

It's the west building of a hospital complex. I can't find how to read it. にしむね? にしとう?

And the rest of the cardinal points?

Comment: I tried a few web searches and there seems to be a fairly strong consensus that this is にしとう in the context you describe, and にしむね as a surname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

西棟, 東棟, 北棟 and 南棟 are read にしとう, ひがしとう, きたとう and みなみとう, respectively. More generally, 棟 as a naming suffix for a modern building is always とう.

- 第3研究棟【けんきゅうとう】: Research Building 3
- 本部棟【ほんぶとう】: Headquarters Building
- 中央棟【ちゅうおうとう】: Central Building
- 新棟【しんとう】: New Building
- 管理棟【かんりとう】: Administration Building